Characters with accents and '?' symbol in the exported CSV file
When opening the exported CSV file, some characters have the '?' symbol. Why is this happening?
The command that was executed in SQL Plus was:
I open the CMD, go to the path 'instantclient_18_5' and type the command:
username/password@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.20.4.5)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=name)))"

and then I type:
@oracle.<tablename>.sql <filename>.csv

When opening this filename, the characters with accents have the '?' symbol.
The NLS_CHARACTERSET in the database is WE8MSWIN1252.
And the NLS_LANGUAGE is BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE.
The database is Oracle.
How would I solve this problem?
Contents of @oracle.<tablename>.sql
set colsep ';'
set echo off
set feedback off
set linesize 32766
set pagesize 0
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set trimout on
set headset off
set trim on
set wrap on

SET TERMOUT OFF
spool &1
SELECT
 TRIM(PLATE) || ';' ||
 TRIM(NAME) || ';' ||
 TRIM(END_LOGRADOURO) || ';' ||
 TRIM(END_NUMBER) || ';' ||
 TRIM(END_COMPLEMENTO) || ';' ||
 TRIM(END_BAIRRO) || ';' ||
 TRIM(END_CITY) || ';' ||
 TRIM(END_CEP) || ';' ||
 TRIM(TRANSPORT_MODALITY) || ';' ||
TRIM(PREFIX) || ';' ||
TRIM(CPF_CNPJ)
FROM SISFROTA.VEIC_ALTERNATIVOS va;
spool off
exit

Thanks

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278790/plsql-special-character-in-input-parameter-is-not-being-passed/44279154#44279154 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

@Wernfried Domscheit I didn't find a solution.

Then ask different: what is the character set of your cmd? What is your NLS_LANG value? How do you open the CSV file?

@Wernfried Domscheit The Database's NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8MSWIN1252 and the NS_LANGUAGE is BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE. I open the CSV file in Excel itself, and in Excel I see the symbol '?' in the accents.

That's not what I have asked for! (the information you gave, is rather irrelevant for your question) Have a careful look at the answers I provided in my comment. Try to open the file with a different tool, e.g. a text editor.

Looks like Excel is not the best tool to open CSV files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508558/what-charset-does-microsoft-excel-use-when-saving-files or https://superuser.com/questions/1688716/excel-2019-default-encoding-for-csv-files

@Wernfried Domscheit I opened the CSV file with a text editor, the delimiter is ';' and the accentuation errors continue.

What do you mean by "I didn't find a solution"? What did you try? Do you see correct characters when you query the database with a different tool? What is the output when you query DUMP(..., 1024)?

When I say I didn't find a solution, it means I tried a few ways and couldn't. I tried to put some converts in the .sql, but without success, I use this CSV file to import into another table. I tested it in other database tools and all the queries have the correct accentuation.

Please edit your question and show exactly what you have done. Usually it should work just by setting NLS_LANG correctly. However, you don't provide any information to give you any help.
